# C Server Side ssh library

Tags: open-source, library, c, ssh

I need to use some kind of ssh library that has server side implementation for my embedded system

The solution should comply to the following requirements:

- The ability to have some callback mechanism for things like memory management
- The ability to compile on multiple architectures

What library do you recommend?

I prefer the library to be open source

So far I found libssh2 that implements the callback mechanism but only implement the client side while libssh implements the client side but doesn't implement the memory callback mechanism

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, [`libssh`](http://www.libssh.org/) is your only chance for C. The other [`libssh2`](https://www.libssh2.org/) does not support server side. There is simple [comparison](https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2-vs-libssh.html) of these two.

I am not sure what you mean by "callback mechanism for things like memory management" and what exactly you want to do with the server side ssh library, but for the reference, there is the [comparison of all the SSH implementations](http://ssh-comparison.quendi.de/) (not only libraries). You might be able to hook your stuff event to real `ssh` server from Dropbear, OpenSSH or Apache SSHD.

Comment: by callback for memory management i mean that i can use something other than malloc to allocate memory,some embedded systems doesn't use the standard memory management functions

Comment: AFAIK, Dropbear is made for embedded systems, so it should certainly support something like this.

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, there are more C libraries that allow to implement an embedded SSH server. The three libraries listed below are open source and designed to be portable:

- [libassh](http://libassh.org) (LGPL 2.1)
- [CycloneSSH](https://oryx-embedded.com/products/CycloneSSH.html) (GPL 2 or commercial)
- [wolfSSH](https://www.wolfssl.com/products/wolfssh/) (GPL 3 or commercial)

Comment: You are missing libssh, which was still there in 2021 and is still here in 2024.